# QQmlApplicationEngine not emitting warnings signal

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I am loading a QML file in PyQt application and I would like to display error and warning messages in case QML file is not valid. QQmlApplicationEngine should emit `warnings` signal in that case, but that doesn't appear to happen. In code below, if QML file contains errors, it is not loaded but `display_warnings` slot is never called. What am I doing wrong? PyQt version is 5.9.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

def display_warnings(warnings):
    pass # Process warnings

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    import sys
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.warnings.connect(display_warnings)
    qml_filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'MainWindow.qml')
    engine.load(qml_filename)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how does it work in Python but in C++ that works well ie. reports about all QML errors:

```cpp
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::warnings, [=] (const QList<QQmlError> &warnings) {
    foreach (const QQmlError &error, warnings) {
        qWarning() << "warning: " << error.toString();
    }
});
```

Note that in this case the type of connection is `Qt::DirectConnection`.
In fact all the errors are the same as console ones.

In my test the error this code error `anchors.centerIn: parnt` will be reported twice, one error by console and one error by `warnings` signal handler:

> warning:  "qrc:/main.qml:13: ReferenceError: parnt is not defined"
>
> qrc:/main.qml:13: ReferenceError: parnt is not defined

So you should check if your QML code contains error at all and also check if your console produces some warnings.

Comment: QML code definitely contains errors, but nothing is displayed in the console. It's probably a PyQt problem, but there is not much about QQmlApplicationEngine in PyQt docs.

Comment: see [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991306/pyside-how-to-see-qml-errors-in-python-console)